# Insert a div after the 3rd product in woocommerce shop

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using 3 columns grid in woocommerce shop

```
[] [] []
[] [] []
[] [] []
```

How can I insert a div after the 3rd grid

Something like this

```
[][][inserted div]
[][][]
[][][]
```

So I can put anything in there, thanks.

Comment: You just want to add class or insert new div ?

Comment: Please add you code in your question and you have tried.

Comment: Check the answer given by me

Comment: Hi @Jalpa , want to insert a new div, i want to put ads in there

Comment: @FrancisAlvinTan did you manage to solve this? What did you do?

Answer (score 2):

All the product loaded from a loop script just initiate any `$variable= 0` and after every product loaded `$variable incremented by 1` and check `$variable %3 == 0` if success add the div

> e.g.

```
$variable = 0;

{ //product loop start 

//product load

$variable ++; // variable increment
if($variable%3 == 0){
// Add Div here
}
} //product loop end
```

Comment: Hi, im sorry but where do I put this code in? not really good at this :-(

Comment: In the product listing template file from where the listing page is coming

Comment: Although this will work it is not the best solution as it requires directly modifying the loop code in the template. In the case of Woocommerce there are actions embedded in the loop code which can be used so you don't have to modify the template code which has the disadvantage of needing to be re-patched everytime the plugin/theme is updated. It would be best to put code in functions.php.

Answer (score 1):

You can place this inside your post loop just before the loop ends. It will output your desired div (ad) after the 2nd post. Just make sure you add in any necessary CSS classes to the div, and of course your ad code or image.

```
<?php if ( $wp_query->current_post == 1 ) { ?>

  <div>Put Ad Here</div>

<?php } ?>
```

So it should look something like this within your post loop:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content' ); ?>

        <?php if ( $wp_query->current_post == 1 ) { ?>
             <div>Put Ad Here</div>
        <?php } ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

This works by using the `$current_post` property of the [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) class. It retrieves the index of your current post in the loop.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Although this will work it is not the best solution as it requires directly modifying the loop code in the template. In the case of Woocommerce there are actions embedded in the loop code which can be used so you don't have to modify the template code which has the disadvantage of needing to be re-patched everytime the plugin/theme is updated. It would be best to put code in functions.php.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using jQuery also,

Try the CSS selector :nth-child():

```
$("#holder > div:nth-child(2)").after("<div>add div</div>");
```