# Insert a DIV after the 6th product only once in WooCommerce category archives

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, categories

I would like to show some content after the fifth product of a product category.

Based on [Add content in between product rows in WooCommerce archives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62469930/add-content-in-between-product-rows-in-woocommerce-archives) answers code, I am using this slight modified version code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', 'action_woocommerce_shop_loop', 100 );
function action_woocommerce_shop_loop() {
    // Only on producy cayegory archives
    if ( is_product_category() ) :
        
    global $wp_query;
    
    // Get the number of columns set for this query
    $columns = esc_attr( wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' ) );
    
    // Get the current post count 
    $current_post = $wp_query->current_post;
    
    if ( ( $current_post % $columns ) == 0  && $current_post%6==0 ) :
    
    ?>
        <div class="product-grid-item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><div class="banner"><?php _e("Custom content here"); ?></div></div>
    <?php
    endif; endif;
}
```

This kind of works, but adds the custom content (DIVs) multiple times. It's adding it every 6 columns.  I just need one single DIV after the 6th column.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the content just once after sixth column, just change the if condition to:

```
if ($current_post == 6) :
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also insert the content after any number of posts by using this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', 'action_woocommerce_shop_loop', 100 );
function action_woocommerce_shop_loop() {

    if ( is_product_category() ) :
        
    global $wp_query;
    
    $columns = esc_attr( wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' ) );
    
    $current_post = $wp_query->current_post;
    
    if ( ( $current_post % $columns ) == 0  && (in_array($current_post, array (6, 10, 45)))) :
    
    ?>
   </ul>
    <ul class="columns-1" style="list-style:none; margin:0 0 3em;">
        <li style=""><div class="banner"> 
            
        <!--Insert Ads here -->

        </div></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="products columns-<?php echo $columns; ?>">
    
        <?php
    endif;endif;
}
```